# toast.getView() and toast.setView() is deprecated

Tags: android, android-studio, toast, android-toast

**I want to show custom toast to users. But toast.getView() and toast.setView() is deprecated in android studio.**

Here is my code:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Show Toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = toast.getView();
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toast_background);
TextView text = view.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
text.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
text.setPadding(15,0,15,0);
toast.show();
```

**Now, how to customize toast in android studio(java)?**

Comment: according to the documentation it's not supported for API >=30, and the suggestion is to use Snackbar instead. I guess you could also create a Dialog without buttons, that would be dismissed after specific time, that's probably the closest to the Toast visually

Comment: I will do it. Thanks @Stachu.

Answer (score 0):

Create New Class

```
    public class WhiteCustomToast {
    public static void Make(Context context, String message) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            View view = toast.getView();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_cutom_bg);
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
            //text.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
            text.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            text.setTypeface(Utilities.Ubuntu_Regular);
            text.setTextSize(14f);
        }
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

And Used in Main Class or Every Where

```
WhiteCustomToast.Make(context, "Checking");
```